# Reduce file header block

Tags: oracle, performance, wait-types, oracle-19c

I'm in the middle of my first Statspack analysis, and one of the most time consuming events is Buffer Busy Waits (around 30% time). I checked out the Buffer Wait statistics, and it seems like the most time it's waiting in File Header Block (about 10x more time than the second wait event).
Could you give me a hint how can I approach this issue? The only advice I found online in [this](https://sites.google.com/site/embtdbo/wait-event-documentation/oracle-buffer-busy-wait) site saying

> File Header Block - Most likely extent allocation problems, look at extent size on tablespace and increase the extent size to there are few extent allocations and less contention on the File Header Block.

I was googling again about increasing extent size and I'm bit lost here. Seems that extent size is assigned to particular tablespace, and I would need to replace my tablespaces in order to change that, but that is only for the initial one. How can I increase it without replacing all tablespaces in my DB?

Is there maybe any other stuff I should look into when I see lot of File Header Block waiting time?

Cheers

---

Update1:

```
Tablespace
------------------------------
                 Av      Av     Av                    Av        Buffer Av Buf
         Reads Reads/s Rd(ms) Blks/Rd       Writes Writes/s      Waits Wt(ms)
-------------- ------- ------ ------- ------------ -------- ---------- ------
AA_AAA
       438,217     220    3.8     1.0      788,012      396      2,007   14.3
UNDOTBS1
             0       0    0.0               21,104       11     21,647  993.6
TBS_PERFSTAT
           143       0   40.1     1.0        3,340        2          0    0.0
SYSTEM
            26       0   14.6     1.0          114        0          0    0.0
SYSAUX
            14       0    4.3     1.0           98        0          0    0.0
AA_AAA_IDX
            74       0   15.7     1.0            2        0          4    7.5
BB_BBB
             0       0    0.0                   54        0        820  993.0
BB_BBB_IDX
             0       0    0.0                   40        0      1,527  993.5
          -------------------------------------------------------------
File IO Stats  DB/Inst: ORCL/orcl  Snaps: 9833-9834
->Mx Rd Bkt: Max bucket time for single block read
->ordered by Tablespace, File

Tablespace               Filename
------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------
                        Av   Mx                                             Av
                 Av     Rd   Rd    Av                    Av        Buffer BufWt
         Reads Reads/s (ms)  Bkt Blks/Rd       Writes Writes/s      Waits  (ms)
-------------- ------- ----- --- ------- ------------ -------- ---------- ------
AA_AAA                   /oradata/data_files/ORCL/eim.dbf
             0       0                             54        0        820  993.0

AA_AAA_IDX               /oradata/data_files/ORCL/eim_idx.dbf
             0       0                             40        0      1,527  993.5

BB_BBB                   /oradata/data_files/ORCL/uel.dbf
       438,217     220   3.8   1     1.0      788,012      396      2,007   14.3

BB_BBB_IDX               /oradata/data_files/ORCL/uel_idx.dbf
            74       0  15.7   1     1.0            2        0          4    7.5

SYSAUX                   /oradata/data_files/ORCL/sysaux01.dbf
            14       0   4.3   1     1.0           98        0          0

SYSTEM                   /oradata/data_files/ORCL/system01.dbf
            26       0  14.6   1     1.0          114        0          0

TBS_PERFSTAT             /oradata/data_files/ORCL/statspack_data01.dbf
           143       0  40.1   1     1.0        3,340        2          0

UNDOTBS1                 /oradata/data_files/ORCL/undotbs01.dbf
             0       0                         21,104       11     21,647  993.6

          -------------------------------------------------------------
File Read Histogram Stats  DB/Inst: ORCL/orcl  Snaps: 9833-9834
->Number of single block reads in each time range
->Tempfiles are not included
->ordered by Tablespace, File

Tablespace               Filename
------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------
    0 - 2 ms     2 - 4 ms    4 - 8 ms     8 - 16 ms   16 - 32 ms       32+ ms
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
AA_AAA_IDX               /oradata/data_files/ORCL/uel_idx.dbf
          19            0            0            0            0            0

SYSAUX                   /oradata/data_files/ORCL/sysaux01.dbf
          10            0            0            0            0            0

AA_AAA                   /oradata/data_files/ORCL/uel.dbf
     392,355            0            0            0            0            0

TBS_PERFSTAT             /oradata/data_files/ORCL/statspack_data01.dbf
          29            0            0            0            0            0

SYSTEM                   /oradata/data_files/ORCL/system01.dbf
          18            0            0            0            0            0

          -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is the tablespace ASSM or Dictionary managed?

Comment: @MichaelKutz ASSM

Comment: The block size is assigned to a tablespace (usually 8k by default) and cannot be changed without recreating the tablespace. Extents are collections of contiguous blocks assigned to a specific table or index, which may have many extents. A tablespace may have a default initial extent size (which is often too small), but that can be overridden for individual tables. That said, ASSM should do all that automatically for you; the total number of extents is no longer an issue. The issue in the link you posted only applies to much older versions of Oracle, before ASSM.

Comment: Which tablespace(s) are experiencing the problem? Data, undo, or system?

Comment: @pmdba I think it's data. because the performance problem occurs during heavy insert process that we run periodically. Is there any way to find out exact tablespace that is waiting (I don't think it's an information I can find in Statspack report)?

Comment: The statspack report should include specific I/O metrics for each tablespace and datafile. Have you looked at these links? https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_statspack_survival_guide.html; https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/performance/statspack-tuning-otn-new-128500.pdf

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your statspack output here where we could see it?

Comment: Hi @pmdba, sorry for late response, I was away. Unfortunately I can't publish the whole report as some of object names may contain sensitive information that I'm not allowed to share. I posted a tablespace stats above, it looks like Undo is the one that cause problems